# Can 2h washing pole be parried?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I am really bad and I am really trying to get good. I have the monastery scimitar but my parrying rate seems to be less then 5% in pvp. So I was fighting someone today. They had washing pole and they would walk up to me and spam their rt attack 2 handed. I had the monastery scimitar. If I did it too late they would hit me and i would get stun locked for 3 hits. If I did it too early, i would raise my hand to do the parry animation, and they would stun me out of it. Can 2handed washing pole even be parried? I had 3k health with 1,200 defenses. got beaten by someone with robe armor and a 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Any and all enemies (and weapons) can be parried, with the exception of jumping attacks. It is important to note that there is latency between players fairly often, being anywhere between a .5 - 2 second gap.

Comment: greatswords, greathammers, and greatclubs 2h initial attacks cannot be parried. the secondary attacks, however,  can be parried.  shield bashes, along with arrows and hexes, cannot be parried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although not every weapon can be parried and some weapons are way easier than others to parry.

It doesn't matter what you parry with though, even if some tools to parry (like a 2handed greatsword) are way harder to parry with than others (light shields or curved swords), if it's possible, it is for all weapons.

Some heavy strength weapons have unparryable moves, mostly 2handed RT/R2 attacks.

Examples for unparryable weapons:
- 2handed Curved Greatswords (all but the roll attack)
- Whips
- The R1/RB of the 2handed halberds
- 2handed R2/RT of Syan's Halberd
- 2handed R1/RB and R2/RT of the great hammers, great swords and great axes

(There are exceptions for single weapons, the reason for this is that they might have a different moveset, but these work for almost all weapons)

Answer (score -1):

You can parry the washing pole.

A patch has greatly hurt the parry window of the Monastery Scimitar. **The**

**buckler now has way more active time (compare to the Monastery Scimitar.)**. The

buckler has a slightly slower startup, but that's the ONLY disadvantage.